# NiFi ConvertAvroToParquet IllegalArgumentException You cannot call toBytes() more than once without calling reset()

Tags: java, apache-nifi, avro, parquet

I am not able to convert a 3.7GB avro file to parquet format using ConvertAvroToParquet.

My setup: ExecuteSQL 1.10.0 > ConvertAvroToParquet 1.10.0 > PutS3Object 1.10.0.

[ConvertAvroToParquet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVORw.png) settings are by default.

```
2020-09-24 20:54:40,534 INFO [Write-Ahead Local State Provider Maintenance] org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog org.wali.MinimalLockingWriteAheadLog@6c8e0773 checkpointed with 645 Records and 0 Swap Files in 5 milliseconds (Stop-the-world time = 1 milliseconds, Clear Edit Logs time = 1 millis), max Transaction ID 9971
2020-09-24 20:54:48,015 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
2020-09-24 20:54:48,015 INFO [pool-12-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 2 records in 0 milliseconds
2020-09-24 20:55:03,820 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.p.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 100899470
2020-09-24 20:55:03,953 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.p.parquet.ConvertAvroToParquet ConvertAvroToParquet[id=c08ff95c-0174-1000-9e67-1f59b4d34dfe] ConvertAvroToParquet[id=c08ff95c-0174-1000-9e67-1f59b4d34dfe] failed to process session due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot call toBytes() more than once without calling reset(); Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot call toBytes() more than once without calling reset()
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot call toBytes() more than once without calling reset()
    at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:53)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridEncoder.toBytes(RunLengthBitPackingHybridEncoder.java:254)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridValuesWriter.getBytes(RunLengthBitPackingHybridValuesWriter.java:65)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:148)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.flush(ColumnWriterV1.java:235)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.flush(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:122)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:172)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:114)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.close(ParquetWriter.java:308)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.ConvertAvroToParquet.lambda$onTrigger$0(ConvertAvroToParquet.java:159)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2990)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.ConvertAvroToParquet.onTrigger(ConvertAvroToParquet.java:141)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-09-24 20:55:03,954 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-7] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding ConvertAvroToParquet[id=c08ff95c-0174-1000-9e67-1f59b4d34dfe] due to uncaught Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot call toBytes() more than once without calling reset()
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot call toBytes() more than once without calling reset()
    at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:53)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridEncoder.toBytes(RunLengthBitPackingHybridEncoder.java:254)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridValuesWriter.getBytes(RunLengthBitPackingHybridValuesWriter.java:65)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:148)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.flush(ColumnWriterV1.java:235)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.flush(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:122)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:172)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:114)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.close(ParquetWriter.java:308)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.ConvertAvroToParquet.lambda$onTrigger$0(ConvertAvroToParquet.java:159)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.write(StandardProcessSession.java:2990)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.ConvertAvroToParquet.onTrigger(ConvertAvroToParquet.java:141)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1176)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:213)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-09-24 20:55:52,897 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.p.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 101841856
```

What can this be?

Comment: Could you please give a sample of the avro data?

Comment: [ {
  "tp_resposta_id" : 1,
  "nome" : "MULTIPLA_ESCOLHA",
  "descricao" : "item que indicará a escolha de opção de resposta.",
  "dt_inclusao" : "2020-04-22 10:28:00.0",
  "dt_alteracao" : null,
  "usuario" : "CARGA_CC_3"
}, {
  "tp_resposta_id" : 2,
  "nome" : "TEXTO",
  "descricao" : "item que indicará uma resposta inserida em um campo de texto.",
  "dt_inclusao" : "2020-04-22 10:28:00.0",
  "dt_alteracao" : null,
  "usuario" : "CARGA_CC_3"
}]

Comment: Based on your sample: I did ConvertJsontoAvro then AvroToParquet. I didn't had any issue. What I would do, check if your data from your SQL request are in Avro format(not Json). Check on a smaller file.

Answer (score 0):

I did what you proposed, Pdeuxa, and it worked perfectly for a small table, but not for large table. So, I increased the JVM's heap memory in the `nifi-1.10.0/conf/bootstrap.conf` file, and it worked for me.

### JVM memory settings

```
#java.arg.2=-Xms512m
#java.arg.3=-Xmx512m
java.arg.2=-Xms2048m
java.arg.3=-Xmx2048m
```

Thanks for your time and your attention, Pdeuxa.

Comment: Good to know! We all went to this an increase JVM memory for Nifi.

Answer (score 0):

TL,DR: `ParquetWriter` was interrupted by other exception, and it shouldn't be reused after the exception. In your case, it should be an OOM exception.

I encountered the same issue recently in a project Hudi. This exception was thrown by `ParquetWriter` when I was trying to write a record into a Parquet file.

```
2023-01-31 11:54:20,199 ERROR org.apache.hudi.io.HoodieMergeHandle                         [] - Error writing record  HoodieRecord{key=HoodieKey { recordKey=149389890 partitionPath=}, currentLocation='null', newLocation='null'}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot call toBytes() more than once without calling reset()
    at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:57)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridEncoder.toBytes(RunLengthBitPackingHybridEncoder.java:254)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridValuesWriter.getBytes(RunLengthBitPackingHybridValuesWriter.java:69)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:60)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterBase.writePage(ColumnWriterBase.java:387)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreBase.sizeCheck(ColumnWriteStoreBase.java:235)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreBase.endRecord(ColumnWriteStoreBase.java:222)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.endRecord(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:29)
    at org.apache.parquet.io.MessageColumnIO$MessageColumnIORecordConsumer.endMessage(MessageColumnIO.java:307)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.write(AvroWriteSupport.java:172)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:138)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:310)
    at org.apache.hudi.io.storage.HoodieBaseParquetWriter.write(HoodieBaseParquetWriter.java:80)
    at org.apache.hudi.io.storage.HoodieAvroParquetWriter.writeAvro(HoodieAvroParquetWriter.java:76)
    at org.apache.hudi.io.HoodieMergeHandle.writeToFile(HoodieMergeHandle.java:386)
    at org.apache.hudi.io.HoodieMergeHandle.writeRecord(HoodieMergeHandle.java:315)
    at org.apache.hudi.io.HoodieMergeHandle.writeInsertRecord(HoodieMergeHandle.java:296)
    at org.apache.hudi.io.HoodieMergeHandle.writeIncomingRecords(HoodieMergeHandle.java:399)
    at org.apache.hudi.io.HoodieMergeHandle.close(HoodieMergeHandle.java:414)
    at org.apache.hudi.table.action.commit.FlinkMergeHelper.runMerge(FlinkMergeHelper.java:133)
    at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieFlinkCopyOnWriteTable.handleUpdateInternal(HoodieFlinkCopyOnWriteTable.java:375)
    at org.apache.hudi.table.HoodieFlinkCopyOnWriteTable.handleUpdate(HoodieFlinkCopyOnWriteTable.java:366)
    at org.apache.hudi.table.action.compact.HoodieCompactor.compact(HoodieCompactor.java:238)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.compact.CompactFunction.doCompaction(CompactFunction.java:110)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.compact.CompactFunction.processElement(CompactFunction.java:101)
    at org.apache.hudi.sink.compact.CompactFunction.processElement(CompactFunction.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.processElement(ProcessOperator.java:66)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask$StreamTaskNetworkOutput.emitRecord(OneInputStreamTask.java:233)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.processElement(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:134)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.emitNext(AbstractStreamTaskNetworkInput.java:105)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:524)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:203)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:809)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:758)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:951)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:930)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:744)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:563)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_252]
```

After checking the source code of parquet-column. The cause of this exception is that the parquet writer can't be reused if it was interrupted by other exception. According to the source code of `org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterBase#writePage`, `repetitionLevelColumn`, `definitionLevelColumn` and `dataColumn` will be reset after `writePage(...)`, but the reset code is not in finally block, so, if there is anything wrong in `writePage(...)`, the reset code won't be executed.

```java
abstract class ColumnWriterBase implements ColumnWriter {
  ...
  void writePage() {
    if (valueCount == 0) {
      throw new ParquetEncodingException("writing empty page");
    }
    this.rowsWrittenSoFar += pageRowCount;
    if (DEBUG)
      LOG.debug("write page");
    try {
      writePage(pageRowCount, valueCount, statistics, repetitionLevelColumn, definitionLevelColumn, dataColumn);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ParquetEncodingException("could not write page for " + path, e);
    }
    repetitionLevelColumn.reset();
    definitionLevelColumn.reset();
    dataColumn.reset();
    valueCount = 0;
    resetStatistics();
    pageRowCount = 0;
  }
}
```

In my case, the exception thrown in `writePage(...)` was a class not found exception, and my code caught it wrongly, and want to reuse the same writer.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.luben.zstd.NoPool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.util.ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClassWithoutExceptionHandling(ChildFirstClassLoader.java:74)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.ZstandardCodec.createOutputStream(ZstandardCodec.java:109)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.ZstandardCodec.createOutputStream(ZstandardCodec.java:100)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.CodecFactory$HeapBytesCompressor.compress(CodecFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ColumnChunkPageWriteStore$ColumnChunkPageWriter.writePage(ColumnChunkPageWriteStore.java:168)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterV1.writePage(ColumnWriterV1.java:59)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriterBase.writePage(ColumnWriterBase.java:387)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreBase.sizeCheck(ColumnWriteStoreBase.java:235)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreBase.endRecord(ColumnWriteStoreBase.java:222)
    at org.apache.parquet.column.impl.ColumnWriteStoreV1.endRecord(ColumnWriteStoreV1.java:29)
```